# Snippet in Gmail is showing code

Tags: html, css, email, html-email

I'm sending e-mails created from templates using HTML and CSS in the header.
The e-mail clients I tested are all showing the mail in the way I want it.
Even Gmail shows the mail the correct way.
The problem I've got is that the snippet (pre-header) which is shown in the Gmail-inbox. This snippet shows part of the CSS out of the header of the mail.
Does anybody know how to avoid this without transforming all of the mails to mails with the CSS inline?
The image below shows the problem and part of the mail.
  [image]

Comment: You need to set the content type as HTML and not as plain text.

Comment: As you can see in the picture: the content type is already set to html

Comment: The point is that you should declare the HTML type in the HEADERS of the mail message not in the <head> of the HTML. How to fix this depends in the way you are composing the mail message and on the way you are sending it.

Comment: @MichelvanVuren Content type of the email, not anything inside that.

Comment: @ holden: I'm using a service written in C# which is using SMTP of System.Net.Mail
@holden/Praveen: I'll look into that

Comment: It's been a while i am not into that kind of problems, but, as far as i remember, what i came up with at the end, was converting all the styles into "inline" exacly cause GMAIL...

Comment: The header of the mail: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;

Comment: Changing the Content-Type of the mail did the trick!! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, set content type to `text/html` instead of `text/plain`.

More things to note:

1. You can't just copy-paste HTML page to email and hope it works. [Check here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/) for email supported css.
2. There is no use of `<title>` attribute, because it's not web interface (like MS Outlook).
3. Use inline-css. Some clients don't include non-inline-css.

Sometimes even such great mail clients as GMail will throw your css away (not talking about images and js code). Keep in mind, that there is still clients that serves all emails as `text/plain` no matter what you do.

Comment: The content type was already set to html (as the picture shows).
1. As stated in the question: the html just works fine
2. This is not an issue
3. As stated in the question: I don't want to use inline-css because it is used in multiple templates and using seperate CSS is way easier for changes etc.

Gmail treats the CSS very well in the part of showing the mail contents.
The only problem is the snippet in the inbox-view.

Comment: @MichelvanVuren Do you set content type the way as in `$additional_headers` from http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php or just type it in inside meta tag of template? Does `html works fine` in browser on in email program (two different aspects).

Comment: The problem is solved, see comments to the Original post. I'm using AlternateView from the System.Net.Mail namespace now and excluding the CSS for the plain tekst format and including the CSS for the tekst/html format. Just changing the header of the mail worked fine as well (for Gmail) but now I've got a better solution that will work for plain tekst also.